# Which RPG is being played in Gamers: Dorkness Rising?

Tags: gamers-dorkness-rising

I've seen Gamers 2 several times now, but I've never been sure which RPG they're supposed to be playing.  I believe it's supposed to be DND 3.5, but I am not sure on that.  So, are they playing 3.5?  How can you tell?  If not, what are they playing?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gamers:_Dorkness_Rising#Style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that they are playing DnD 3.5.

More specifically, they are playing the module called *[The Mask of Death](http://www.goodman-games.com/50205preview.html)*, which is a real game.

[image]

From the Mask of Death link:

*This module is a special limited edition produced exclusively for Gen Con Indy 2005. It presents chapter one of an adventure that chronicles the hilarious escapades of the hit film The Gamers: Dorkness Rising.*

More info. can be found on the [wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gamers:_Dorkness_Rising)